# Problems getting a basic JAXRS + JPA version working on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

Using Eclipse Juno Service Release 1, I created a Google App Engine project and then manually copied over the JAX-RS and JAXB jar files in to war/WEB-INF/lib (because trying to add JAX-RS in the 'Project Facets' properties caused errors - i.e. requiring to install Dynamic Web Module which I *think* is not required due to the JAR's already included in the GAE project?

When I run locally, the project starts up okay and I can navigate to my dummy rest service and it all works okay.

When I look at the version deployed on GAE it results in the following stack trace in the log file.

Any assistance on steps to resolve this would be appreciated.

Many thanks!
Rob.

> 2012-11-21 10:35:56.687 /hillingargaeserver 500 2764ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17
>   87.194.162.20 - - [21/Nov/2012:10:35:56 -0800] "GET /hillingargaeserver HTTP/1.1" 500 0
>   "http://hillingartimber.appspot.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel
>   Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17" "hillingartimber.appspot.com" ms=2765
>   cpu_ms=888 loading_request=1
>   instance=00c61b117cfb3272dbda34e1e6d6872973f98c34 C 2012-11-21
>   10:35:56.685 Uncaught exception from servlet
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class    at
>   com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-ca8643ac95d7d414(Request.java)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, I found that I needed to add ALL the JAX-RS Jar files (except in the contrib folder) and JAXB Jar files (with the exception of JavaDoc related ones).

I also shifted the 'Servlet' jars to be before all the others.

A good tip, if you copy the war files in to your /war/WEB-INF/lib folder, you can then right-click on them to add them to your build path!! - Saves having a copy in both the project and WEB-INF folder.

Rob.